# Windows OS: what setting causes a warning yellow triangle exclamation mark overlay displayed over file icons for files downloaded from internet?

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-explorer

I've been trying for sometime to understand what OS setting or application installation determines the display of a warning yellow triangle exclamation mark overlay on top of a file's icon for files downloaded from internet and thus having the ZoneId (zone.identifier) bit set.

Below a screenshot of a couple of files just downloaded from the internet and displaying the warning yellow triangle overlay on top of each file's icon

[image: warning yellow triangle overlay displayed over a file's icon]

Comment: I don't have this overlay. To test if some installed application is adding it, boot the computer in Safe mode.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I was able to identify what application adds this overlay to icons for files that have the ZoneId bit set. For anyone interested, it's ZoneIDTrimmer. The author's site h**p://www.gasanov.net/ does not exist anymore but the application can still be found on the internet.

Comment: why isn't this answer considered useful?

Answer (score 2):

The ZoneId is stored in an NTFS alternative data stream called *Zone.Identifier*.  You can identify files with this alternative data stream using PowerShell:

```
Get-ChildItem c:\downloads\* | Get-Item -Stream Zone.Identifier -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | Select-Object Filename
```

To remove the alternative stream from a file the following PowerShell command will do the trick.

```
Remove-Item "filename" -Stream Zone.Identifier
```

There is also a SysInternals tool available from Microsoft which does the equivalent operation without using PowerShell.   [Sysinternals Streams](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/streams)